# Msbuild CoreCompile depends on targets

Tags: tfs, msbuild

This what we have: ccnet+tfs+msbuild.

The problem is that our build process is too slow because of a lot of projects.

I've made some investigation and thats what I want to do.

After each project have been compiled it's copied from output folder to shared folder, and this operation do in any case even if this project didnt compiled. So I've checked detailed logs of msbuild and thats what i've found :Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files..

This validation action declared in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets. The question is how can I intercept this information, create own target add some condition, and do some kind of trigger, if "Skipping target "CoreCompile" message" is appeared then do not run my copy target and skip it, if project have been compiled then this copy target should run.

Answer (score 6):

I just blogged this at http://sedodream.com/2012/05/14/MSBuildHowToExecuteATargetAfterCoreCompile.aspx but I pasted the content for you below.

I was on StackOverflow today and noticed a question along these lines “[How to I create a target which is executed when CoreCompile is, and that is skipped when CoreCompile is skipped?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10555649/105999)” Below is my answer.

This is a tricky problem to solve for the general case, but it is pretty easy in your case because CoreCompile has special built in support for this scenario. Before I go into the details of how you can accomplish this with CoreCompile let me explain how it works in general.

### Explanation of the general case

In MSBuild targets are skipped due to Incremental Building. Incremental Build is driven purely off of the Inputs and Outputs attributes on the Target itself. The inputs are a list of files that the target will "use" and the outputs are a list of files that are "generated" by the target. I'm using quotes because its a loose concept not a concrete one. To simplify it you can just treat inputs/outputs as lists of files. When the target is about to be executed MSBuild will take the inputs and compare the timestamps of them to the outputs. If all the outputs are newer then the inputs then the target will be skipped. (FYI If you want to know what happens when only some outputs are out-of-date read my blog at http://sedodream.com/2010/09/23/MSBuildYouveHeardOfIncrementalBuildingButHaveYouHeardOfPartialBuilding.aspx).

In any case if you want a target to be skipped you have to craft your Inputs/Outputs correctly. In your case you want to skip your target whenever the CoreCompile is skipped, so at the surface it would seem that you could simply copy the Inputs/Outputs of CoreCompile but that doesn't work. It doesn't work because when CoreCompile is executed the files may be out-of-date but that target itself brings them up-to-date. Then when you target is executed since they are all up-to-date it will be skipped. You would have to copy the Inputs/Outputs and append an additional file to inputs/outputs which you target creates. This would ensure that your target wouldn't get skipped during that first pass.

### Specific solution for CoreCompile

If you take a look at the project file you will see towards the bottom that the file Microsoft.Common.targets is Imported, this file will then import the language specific .targets file. For example it will Import either Microsoft.CSharp.targets or Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets (if you are using C# or VB). In those .targets files you will find CoreCompile defined. In the definition for CoreCompile you will find the following at the end.

```
<CallTarget Targets="$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)" Condition="'$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)' != ''"/>
```

This will call all the targets defined in the `TargetsTriggeredByCompilation` property. So if you want your target to be called whenever CoreCompile is **executed** you can extend that property. Here is how to do that.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetsTriggeredByCompilation>
    $(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation);
    MyCustomTarget
  </TargetsTriggeredByCompilation>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="MyCustomTarget">
  <Message Text="MyCustomTarget called" Importance ="high"/>
</Target>
```

In this case I define the property **TargetsTriggeredByCompilation** and I append MyCustomTarget to it. It's very important that you include the **$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation);** there, if you don't then you won't be appending but overwriting. So if anyone else used this technique you'd wipe out their target.

Below is an image showing where I build once and CoreCompile and MyCustomTarget are executed. Then the second build CoreCompile is skipped any MyCustomTarget is never called.

[image]

Comment: I had the following error in the log:Task "CallTarget" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != ''). I've even try to comment my extended property, but I got the same message in the log. Is there any ideas ?

Comment: This is what I've add into my project:                  <PropertyGroup>
 <TargetsTriggeredByCompilation>
      $(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation);
      MyCustomTarget
    </TargetsTriggeredByCompilation> 
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="MyCustomTarget" >
    <Message Importance="high" Text="TestMessage:Success" />
  </Target>  I've even checked for existance of this block in common targets in core compile <CallTarget Targets="$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)" Condition="'$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)' != ''"/> and it is there

Comment: I've made some investigation: It works only if I define those property TargetsTriggeredByCompilation in Microsoft.Csharp.Targets but it is unacceptible. I can't modify Microsoft.Csharp.Targets forwardly.

Comment: And it works if I will add those property in Microsoft.Common.Targets as well. But how to make this work if I need to add this property into my custom .proj file?

Comment: When you say custom .proj file do you mean the .csproj/.vbproj for the project itself or something else? If you mean another file which drives those via the MSBuild task then this approach won't work. You'll need to revise your question with more details.

Comment: Content of custom.proj: <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectFile>TestDir/Myproject.csproj</ProjectFile>
 <IsWebProject>False</IsWebProject>
    </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="shared.proj"/>
</Project> shared.proj is used for all our project, it has some predefined custom properties and targets like clean, build etc. Actually I've tried to add TargetsTriggeredByCompilation property in shared.proj and in custom.proj but it doesnt work. Any way Im very appreciated for your help.

Comment: That's going to be a bit more difficult. Can you simply edit the .csproj/.vbproj file?

Comment: I've sold the problem with passing values by write my True or False flag to the file on file system and then read this value, in such case Im bypassing unnecessary import of project. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing but likewise don't want to edit the Microsoft.Csharp.Targets file. Sayed did you get this working without editing them? I added the code as suggested to my build script but it doesn't appear to be adding MyCustomTarget so nothing gets called :(

Comment: @Akuma sorry i'm having a hard time following this thread I think its all over the place. Can you open a new question with details and link back to this one? After that I may be able to help.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi Don't worry I was being stupid putting your suggested code into our build script instead of the csproj file. it works as you explained now that I have done that. Thanks!

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi By the way, please see my new question, your input would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be so much easier if we could just set a condition based on some predicate HasTargetExecuted(CoreCompile), which would evaluate false if the target was skipped and true if it ran, or even a simple property DidCoreCompileRun, something like that. Oh well, thanks for the explanation, at least this is a way to get it done for now.